# Coldfusion: Share session between an iPhone APP and the webview with CFID and CFTOKEN

Tags: coldfusion

we are working on a mobile application for a dating site, mixing native views and web views.

The user need to log in into the iPhone app.
This is done with a webservice (WS). The WS checks the username/password in the database, then creates all the session variables and finally returns the CFID/CFTOKEN to the application.

But when the application try to call a web view including the CFID/CFTOKEN in the URL, the session is not set, and the user has to log in again in the webview... When he logs in again, then the session is created and stay active as usual.

Does I understand well the use of CFID/CFTOKEN ?
How to handle the session between 2 applications?

Thanks for your time !

---

Thank you for your answers. As Jason said, the web views are within the iphone app and we are on ColdFusion 8 The process i need to develop is the following: 1 - the user open the app and fill in his credentials 2 - the app authenticates him with a webservice 3 - the session is created 4 - the user navigate through the application (wich is webservice-based, no problem here...) 5 - some parts (80%) of the screens of application are webviews (non-native). When the user goes to webviews, he needs to be logged in automatically.

My idea was to authenticate the user with the webservice, then returns the CFID/CFTOKEN to the app, and append it to the url of each web view. But this do not work, the user has to log in twice, once in the app, once in the webviews.

Comment: I am confused, are they two different applications or two different ways of accessing the same application?  I think the reason for your issue is the fact cookies are set in the iPhone app but not in safari (assuming that is how you are accessing the web view).  Without the cookie being set in both places it will cause the web view to prompt for a login.

Comment: I am 99% certain that the OP is talking about a web view within his iPhone application. I am not familiar with how the WebView component makes its request. I would suspect it could probably pass along cookies, but if valid CFID and CFToken are sent along in the URL then CF should continue the session. But that is a PITA because then you need to pass them along on every request. It would be best if the webview could use any cookies that the wrapping application has stored (if any)

Comment: This question cannot be accurately answered without another key piece of information that needs to be provided from the asker:

Where does your Application.cfc reside, directory-structure wise, in relation to the WebService, and what are its settings?